Blazorise datagrid RowStyling doesnt work as expected
I'm using blazorise data grid for displaying data. My question is, there is a big gap between 2 rows. I try to use below code, but it not work at all.
  <DataGrid TItem="DailyRecordDto"
        Data="dailyRecordData"
        ReadData="OnDataGridReadAsync"
        CurrentPage="CurrentPage"
        ShowPager="false"
        PageSize="PageSize"
        Responsive
        Resizable
        RowStyling="@OnRowStyling">

@code
  private void OnRowStyling(DailyRecordDto dailyRec, DataGridRowStyling styling)
  {
      styling.Style = "height: 10px;";//I added 100px for checking this code is working. yes. the code is working.
  }

If I use 10px, it's still not nice. (I just try to remove the button, still same happens) UI is having a lot of empty spaces. I need to have a compact look.

As you can see there are 4 records, but we can represent all 4 data with 2 rows' space.
Is there any expert can give a guidance to fulfil my task?
